# Shortcut to create javascript custom error objects using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, error-handling, underscore.js

Is there a clean way to somehow use underscore.js _.extend function (or any other) to create custom Error classes that inherit from base Error class? I'm looking for a backbone-like way to do this.

Tried this :

```
InternalError = function(message, args) {
    message || (message = {});
    this.initialize(message, args);
};
_.extend(InternalError.prototype, Error.prototype, {
    initialize: function(message, args) {
        this.message = message;
        this.name = 'InternalError';
    }
});

var error1 = new Error('foo');
var error2 = new InternalError('bar');
console.warn(error1, error2);
throw error2;
```

But it is not working :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(**Excuse my small parenthesis about prototypal inheritance. You can skip this and see the answer below.

In order for an object to extend another one, the `child`'s prototype must be an instance of it's `parent`. You can find many good resources on the web about this, but, unfortunately, many bad ones as well, so I recommend you take a peak at this article : http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html .
A **new object** instantiated via the `new` keyword  : `new f()` returns a copy of it's prototype object : `f.prototype`. Acknowledging this, you realize that in order to extend an object `x`, your current object's prototype must be a new x instance :

```
function Person(){};
Person.prototype.speak = function(){
    alert("I'm a person");
}
function StackoverflowUser(){};
StackoverflowUser.prototype = new Person();
// now StackOverflowUser is a Person too
```

**)**

you don't actually need underscore.js for that :

```
var InternalError = function(msg,args){
    return this.initialize(msg||{},args);
}

// inherit from the Error object
InternalError.prototype = new Error();

// overwrite the constructor prop too
InternalError.constructor = InternalError;
InternalError.prototype.initialize = function(msg,args){
    this.message = msg;
    this.name = 'InternalError';
}

var err = new InternalError("I'm an internal error!");
alert(err instanceof Error); // true
throw err;
```

if you really want to use underscore.js :

```
var InternalError = function(msg,args){
    return this.initialize(msg||{},args);
}
_.extend(InternalError.prototype,new Error(),{
    initialize : function(msg,args){
        this.message = msg;
        this.name = 'InternalError';
    },
    constructor : InternalError
});
```

Comment: +1, and good answer, but I would specify `InternalError.prototype.constructor = InternalError`, rather than setting `constructor` as an instance property.

Comment: thx, I've updated the examples to include the constructor in the prototype.

Comment: @gion_13 it seems you are still using `InternalError.constructor = InternalError;` rather than `InternalError.prototype.constructor = InternalError` as suggested

Answer (score -3):

Extending the error object (and host objects in general) does not work in all browsers. `Error.prototype` doesn't even exist on IE. There is no need to extend the `Error` object though, just using any custom object will do, even object literals: `{message: 'Really bad error}`.

Comment: -1 for *"`Error.prototype` doesn't even exist on IE"*, which is incorrect.  Also, `Error` is not a host object.  Even if it were, IE has had `prototype` for *most* host objects since IE 8.  Extending the `Error` object should be possible in all browsers implementing at least the 3rd edition of ECMA-262.